Null sets, zero measure sets, and complete probability spaces
Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ denote a probability space, and $\mathscr{F}$ a Borel $\sigma$-field of subsets of $\Omega$. I am interested in the interplay between the following two definitions of zero measure and null sets.
I understand this is well trodden territory, but I cannot seem to find an answer to my specific question (regarding equation 1 and whether or not the inclusion is strict). Apologies if in fact I have missed this. Along the way I have a few assertions denoted [?] which may be incorrect, and which may be the source of my confusion regarding my question. As ever any help greatly appreciated.
Zero $\mu$-measure sets (denote by $\mathcal{C}$): For any space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ we have $\mu(B)=0$ for all $B\in\mathcal{C}$
Since $\mu$ is assigning a measure to $B$ this also implies $B\in\mathscr{F}$, and hence $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathscr{F}$ [?]
$\mu$-null sets (denote by $\mathcal{N}$): For any space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$, for all $A\in\mathcal{N}$ there exists some $B\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $A\subset B$.
Since $\mu$ is a measure, if $A,B\in\mathscr{F}$ then the monotonicity property of measures (if we were permitted to use it) would mean that $A\subset B$ implies $\mu(A)< \mu(B)=0$, which in turn would imply $\mu(A)=0$. We would then conclude $A\in\mathcal{C}$ and hence that $\mathcal{N}\subseteq\mathcal{C}$. However we only know $B\in\mathscr{F}$, but not whether $A\in\mathscr{F}$ is true - this is what the definition of completeness of the probability space achieves [?];
Complete probability space: the space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ is complete if $A\subset B$ for $B\in \mathscr{F}$ and $\mu(B)=0$ imply $A\in\mathscr{F}$.
From the definition of $\mathcal{C}$ we have $B\in\mathcal{C}$ which implies $A\in\mathcal{N}$, and hence $\mathcal{N}\subseteq\mathscr{F}$ must hold. Thus the $\sigma$-field $\mathscr{F}$ contains all of the $\mu$-null sets if it belongs to a complete probability space. [?] A nice example of why complete probability spaces are desired can be found
here.
We can now show $\mathcal{N}\subseteq\mathcal{C}$ in a complete probability space using the monotonicity argument which previously was unavailable to us: choose $A\in\mathcal{N}\subset\mathscr{F}$. Then $A\subset B$ for some $B\in\mathcal{C}\subset\mathscr{F}$. Since $A,B\in\mathscr{F}$ then $A\subset B$ implies $\mu(A)< \mu(B)=0$ which in turn implies $\mu(A)=0$, and hence $A\in\mathcal{C}$ must be true which implies
$$\mathcal{N}\subseteq\mathcal{C}\subset\mathscr{F}\hspace{100pt}[1]$$
But is this inclusion strict? That is, can we find a set $B\in\mathcal{C}\backslash\mathcal{N}$? Assume the opposite and derive a contradiction: since $\mathcal{C}\backslash\mathcal{N}$ is empty then $A\in\mathcal{C}$ implies $A\in\mathcal{N}$, which implies the existence of a set $B\in\mathcal{C}$ satisfying $A\subset B$. Thus for every zero-measure set $A$ we can always find a larger zero measure set $B$ that entirely contains $A$.[??]
This is about as far as I have got. The above seems like it should lead to a contradiction since this seems to be saying the zero-measure sets just keep getting bigger?

update
I believe the following arguments show the inclusion in [1] is strict for a complete probability space;
Assume $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{N}$ and choose $A\in\mathcal{C}$. Then $A\in\mathcal{N}$, so there exists a $B\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $A\subset B$. Since $A,B\in\mathscr{F}$ then $A\subset B$ implies $0=\mu(C)<\mu(B)=0$ which is a contradiction. In combination with [1] conclude
$$\mathcal{N}\subset\mathcal{C}\subset\mathscr{F}\hspace{100pt}[2]$$
If [2] is indeed correct, then I suppose I am struggling to find an explicit example for a set in $\mathcal{C}\backslash\mathcal{N}$, as the attempt following [1] shows.

So what is your question? Whether all null sets are always in the $\sigma$-algebra? Whether this is true for a complete measure?

Hi @tomasz. Primarily I want to know if it is possible to have a zero measure set that is not null?

I think you just misunderstood the definition. $\subset$ is sometimes used, especially in older texts, to denote inclusion, not necessarily strict. So trivially, every set of zero measure is null (because it is its own subset).
If you insist on a strict inclusion, then no, this is not true. For instance, consider $X=\{0,1\}$, $\Sigma=\mathcal P(X)$, $\mu(\{0\})=0, \mu(\{1\})=1$. Then $C=\{0\}$ has zero measure, but the only proper superset has measure $1$. Similarly, if $X$, $\Sigma$ are arbitrary and $\mu$ is the zero measure, then $X$ has measure zero, but it has no proper supersets.
If you have a nonatomic and nonzero measure, then then this distinction does not appear, since every nonempty measurable set contains a nonempty set of zero measure. Thus if $A\subseteq X$ has zero measure, then $A\neq X$ (because $\mu$ is nonzero), so $X\setminus A$ contains a nonempty set $B$ of zero measure, and then $A\subsetneq A\cup B$ and $A\cup B$ has zero measure.

wow - this use of $\subset$ to mean $\subseteq$ has always bothered me, and yes I see now: $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{N}$ with $\subseteq$ in definition of $\mathcal{N}$ since for $A\subseteq X$ we trivially have $A\subseteq A$. Nice example too of $X={0,1}$, giving $\mathcal{P}={\emptyset,{0},{1},X}$ and (I think)
$\mathcal{C}={\emptyset,{0}}$ and $\mathcal{N}={\emptyset}$. The space is complete since $\mathcal{N}\subset\Sigma$ and $\mathcal{N}\subset\mathcal{C}$ and hence a counter-example to the claim $\mathcal{C}\backslash\mathcal{N}\not=\emptyset$ for complete spaces

So using $\subseteq$ in all definitions we have $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{N}$ and for a complete space we also have $\mathcal{N}\subset\mathscr{F}$. If we choose $A\in\mathcal{N}\in\mathscr{F}$ there exists a $B\in\mathcal{C}\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $A\subseteq B$, implying  $\mu(A)\leq\mu(B)=0$ and hence $A\in\mathcal{C}$ since $\mu(A)=0$ must hold. This all implies $\mathcal{N}\subseteq\mathcal{C}$. So we have $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{N}\subset\mathscr{F}$ for a complete space?

Thanks tomaz for the insights - the example of an atomic space I will need to think on some more. I have encountered atoms before but not too much.

@dandar: Yes. That is an equivalent definition of completeness of a measure space. Mind, the last paragraph is concerned with nonatomic spaces. The atomic example is the $X={0,1}$.
